# What can go wrong in hibernate domain classes – so that we need to (unit) test them?

Tags: hibernate, unit-testing

**What can go wrong?**

I have started writing hibernate domain classes for my new J2EE project and during my initial analysis I felt that the following things can go wrong in domain classes that warrants me to have automated tests written for them to capture them in advance:

1. Attribute/column mappings – I might by mistake configure a wrong column to a given attribute in the domain class
2. I might change the database column name(s) and forget to change the corresponding mapping(s) in the domain class file
3. I might forget to set the object attribute in the constructor.  This can happen during the class creation time or while testing something by commenting out some attributes but forgetting to un-comment them back.  (I have done this mistake in real life).
4. I have NOT defined the attributes with the correct data types for the corresponding database column types.
5. Boundary conditions testing to ensure that we have the right sized data types defined for the attributes.  This will also capture any inadvertent changes to the data types in the future, say from long to int.

Whether testing a domain class against these changes is called unit testing or not, I am not really sure as it involved database while testing.  What I need is a way to test my domain classes to ensure that they are NOT broken due to any such above mentioned changes, inadvertently, of-course.

Important Assumption: The database entities (tables, constraints, indexes) have been created accurately and there are no errors in them, as in, the data types, size etc. have been defined accurately.
In other words, as part of the ‘(unit) testing of the domain classes’, we won’t be testing the schema for potential errors.  Examples below:
* Data types and their sizes are correct
* If required constraints (PK, FK, UK, indexes etc.) are present and they are correct

**Automated testing of the domain classes**

For issues 1, 2, 4 - 
Use: validate in hibernate configuration file.
A simple test to save a record (just mandatory fields is enough) into the table(s) concerned will ensure that these issues are not present in the mappings.  Assertion: There should not be any exception thrown.

For issue 3 – A simple test to save a record with all the fields will capture if there is any field left out.  Assertion: There should not be any exception thrown.

For issue 5 – Test case is needed that will insert a record with all the fields with max boundary conditions.  Assertion: There should not be any exception thrown.

Summary: A test case to save a record with all the fields populated with max boundary values will be good enough to test the hibernate domain classes.  Assertion: There should not be any exception thrown.

**Questions**

1. Does the above argument make sense?  If not, why?
2. If it makes sense, what is the right technology for the actual implementation?  Would that be JUnit or TestNG, etc.?

Thanks in advance for your inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumptions are correct, it is important to have unit tests for the domain model, in order to run them every time the database changes as well as the entities. 
I am using similar procedure for testing JPA entities, having implemented the base framework of creating JUnit tests for testing the default designed CRUD functionality.
The tests are run by calling the functions of the DAO controllers, in order to test those as well, since these functions also depend on the structure of the entities and their relationships.
Then tests related to the specific model and logic are also added e.g. a master-detail relationship where cascade delete is not allowed, or only allow something to happen if a condition is met etc.

To your list of checks, at point 5 also add other validation checks i.e. not nullable fields, unique constraints etc.

JUnit has only been mentioned because i have used it successfully, nunit, testng or any other unit testing framework could be used.

Answer (score 1):

> 1) Does the above argument make sense? If not, why?

- Yes

> 2) If it makes sense, what is the right technology for the actual implementation? Would that be JUnit or TestNG, etc.?

- Junit ( http://junit.org/ ) **with** PowerMock ( https://code.google.com/p/powermock ) **with** Mockito ( https://code.google.com/p/mockito/ )

  **OR**
- Junit **with** PowerMock **with** EasyMock (http://easymock.org/).