# Automated testing of domain classes (Not unit testing)

Tags: hibernate, unit-testing

**Current Issue**

Please refer to the related post: [What can go wrong in hibernate domain classes – so that we need to (unit) test them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19866879/what-can-go-wrong-in-hibernate-domain-classes-so-that-we-need-to-unit-test-t)
In my new J2EE project, I am trying to test (NOT necessarily unit tests) the domain objects I have starting writing.  They don't involve much of business logic (the business logic is part of the business service on top of the DAO objects) and by testing, I am essentially ensuring the integrity of the domain objects and I try to do that by testing the DAO methods.  Note that I can NOT test the domain objects using JUnit etc as they don't have any methods in my case and they have attributes and hibernate mapping annotations.

For example, let me consider *Patient* domain object.  *PatientDAO* is dealing with the CRUD operations of Patient domain object in this case.  Here are the methods (not complete and intending to add more to test the boundary conditions little later).

Note: I am NOT calling these as Unit test cases, they may be mini integration tests etc.  I am fine it this approach works in testing the domain objects.

PatientDAOTest class contains:
*- testCreatePatient();
- testUpdatePatient();
- testFindPatient();
- testDeletePatient();*

PatientDAO class contains:
*- createPatient();
- updatePatient();
- findPatient();
- deletePatient();*

Lets us consider testUpdatePatient() method that tests updateMethod() in the domain object.  Now, how am I going to implement testUpdatePatient() method?  Well, I am thinking like:
1. Get the existing patient using 'findPatient()' domain method
2. Update the patient record with the new details
3. Save it back in the database using 'updatePatient()' domain method
4. Retrieve the patient record back from the database using 'findPatient()' domain method
5. Assert for the updated data

**Question**

As you can see, I am using the database in the testing, which I am fine with, but are there any issues with this approach?

**What is my real question (read as issue) about this approach?**

I need to use '*findPatient*()' method (in fact 2 times) while testing '*updatePatient*()'.  This is what I don't like, that fact that I have to use another method while testing a method, while the other method itself could be buggy.  The same story repeats when I try to test the other CRUD methods as well.

Alternatively, I could write select sql query to fetch the patient record from the database for asserting (after update is fired) from the test method, but it just defeats the whole purpose of using hibernate (to reduce the SQL coding effort), hence, I don't like this approach.

My question is, it is common to depend on other methods to test a particular methods and is this a not a bad approach?  If this is wrong, how should I actually test the ORM mapping in my domain objects.

Thanks for your comments and apologies for such a lengthy post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my experiece, answer to your main concern is simple, but you have several other conceptual issues here.

1. It is perfectly OK to include use a feature (findPatient) insede test of another feature (updatePatient), but ONLY if you have another test, that covers findPatient itself alone.
2. For the methodical part of DB-integration testing, you may consider using deditaced auto-test DB, clear all the data and init it to the desired state as a setUp of your unit test. Init your DB with sample inital data using pure SQL scripts (TRUNCATE TABLE Patients; INSERT INTO Patients ...) - what I used to do is switching between several named DB initial data states (e.g. "cleanDB", "twoPatientsSimple1", "twoPatientsLenkedToInsuranceContracts1" etc.). The point here is, your DB gets changed during the unit tests, and using pure ROLLBACK to get into the state before the test doesn't ensure the exact state you want (e.g. you might explicitely commit during the test, and your data gets into another than initial state). You may also include tests to assure DB state after the test changes it, again with pure SQL. Testing using this approach is generally slow to execute and harder to maintain (unless you have a set of our own helper tools), but it gives you full confidence in your data and behavior. After you have done this clearly, it saves you lots of time and confusion during UI/Functional testing. It can soun horrible, but when you play with it a little bit, you end up with simple sets of DB state data (e.g. represented as TSVs/CSVs inside your test cases) "initState" and "expectedState", and you just use these states to init/compare before/after the tested behavior.
3. For the true unit-testing of domain objects (not integrated with DB), you have to mock your DAO/Repository/DataMapper classes, e.g. with simple List generics (createPatient adds it into the list etc.)
4. For integration testing of an ORM itself (your own, 3rd party, or your extension of one), you would use the method in point 2 with some sample data (not necessarilly your domain objects) complicated enough to give you confidence about how your ORM works. E.g. Microsoft Entity Framework worked very unpredictably in early stages, so writing complete integration test of features you typically use can avoid debugging bugs and issues with ORM itself, and shows you, how exactly the ORM behaves under various conditions.